# Completing Strapi API call with React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, strapi

configured Strapi to retrieve a simple list of products. Trying to code the React hook to grab all the products and then render with the `ProductItem` component for each item.  When I use the `useQuery()` hook, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

Here is the hook function accessing Strapi:

```
export default function ProductList() {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useQuery('Products', () => 
    axios('/api/products').then((res) => res.data.products)
  );

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />

  return products.map((product) => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} /> 
  ));
}
```

And here is the layout component that is used to render and layout each entry:

```
function ProductItem({ product }) {
  const price = formatProductPrice(product);

  return (
    <div className="p-4 md:w-1/3">
      <div className="h-full border-2 border-gray-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
        <Link to={`/${product.id}`}>
          <img 
            className="lg:h-96 md:h-36 w-full object-cover object-center"
            src={product.image}
            alt={product.name}
          />
        </Link>
        <div className="p-6">
          <h2 className="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-500 mb-1">
            {product.category}
          </h2>
          <h1 className="title-font text-lg font-medium text-white mb-3">
            {product.name}
          </h1>
          <p className="leading-relaxed mb-3">{product.description}</p>
          <div className="flex items-center flex-wrap ">
            <Link to={`/${product.id}`} className="text-indigo-400 inline-flex items-center md:mb-2 lg:mb-0">
              See More
              <svg
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                strokeWidth="2"
                className="w-4 h-4 ml-2"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              >
                <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
              </svg>
            </Link>
            <span className="text-gray-500 mr-3 inline-flex items-center lg:ml-auto md:ml-0 ml-auto leading-none text-lg pr-3 py-1 border-gray-800 font-bold">
              {price}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tested, and I am receiving the data back in the object, so the data is there. I don't think I am accessing the object correctly or perhaps a plurality issue?  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am accessing the strapi api correctly through the proxy in `package.json` like so:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:1337"
```

If I hit the API directly with `https://localhost:1337/api/products` it works and I get back the JSON fine. It has to be in the React hook I think.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong in the hook code with the .map() ?  I am assuming that Strapi automatically assigns the `id` field and sends it back with the response.

JSON received from Strapi:

```
data: [{id: 1, attributes: {name: "The Contemplation of Union",…}},…],…}
data: [{id: 1, attributes: {name: "The Contemplation of Union",…}},…]
    0: {id: 1, attributes: {name: "The Contemplation of Union",…}}
    attributes: {name: "The Contemplation of Union",…}
    createdAt: "2022-05-01T02:07:51.795Z"
    description_long: "The graphite pencil work that started it 
    all.  Captured second place at the prestigious Brownlee O. 
    Curry Art Competition."
    name: "The Contemplation of Union"
    price: 399
    publishedAt: "2022-05-01T02:07:54.189Z"
    updatedAt: "2022-05-01T02:07:54.191Z"
    id: 1
1: {id: 2, attributes: {name: "Homage to Dali",…}}
2: {id: 3, attributes: {name: "Still Life with Melon",…}}
meta: {pagination: {page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, total: 3}}
pagination: {page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, total: 3}
```

Comment: Look at devtools -> network tab to validate the fetching results status

Comment: put console.log after isloading check condition: console.log(products)

Comment: Thanks for hints.  Network tab is returning JSON ok.  console.log is showing "undefined". hmm.  It has to the way I am constructing the useQuery() call.

Comment: check if data in your json contains products property

Comment: don't see products property, I was thinking that by doing data: products it cast the data key to a products alias. I posted the json received from strapi above

Comment: apparently is mistake, try to use right field in data  array instead of products

Comment: Thanks Oleg, it's very weird how the JSON that returns from Strapi is structured.  It seems to be { data: [{ data: key/value}]. Thanks for the help.  Will keep trying.